# How to use scan command in Arduino WifiBee

Tags: arduino, wifi

We want to find available WiFi networks near.
So in [tutorial](http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/WiFi_Bee_V1.0_(SKU:TEL0067)) there is command scan, which is send from CoolTerm program from PC.

Now we want to write program to Arduino which will do same operation, how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the WifiBee doesn't support network scanning.  You must specify the SSID of the Wifi network that it should connect to, the IP address it expects to be assigned, and the gateway address [as part of its initial configuration](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Wifi_Bee#Downloading_and_configuring_the_Library_for_running_the_application_examples).

Answer (score -4):

> Moderator Note: This answer has been posted by someone related to the
>   product that they are recommending

Sketch Arduino and PIC firmware for Wifly RN-XV modem configuration without Wifly library and with [front-end](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101922388/WiflySanUSB.zip).

Type in browser address bar: 192.168.1.195/YT to toggle LED and open a HTML page.

The microcontroller can be, with this firmware and Wifly, a server (switching the LED signal through 192.168.1.195/YT in address bar) 
or also client (the AD converter value is inserted in google databank).

Comment: Welcome to Robotics, SanUSB. While we have no policy that forbids recommending your own product, the community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you **must** disclose your affiliation in your answers. Please familiarise yourself with the [help] pages, especially the page on [user behaviour](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)